# Blender Compositing Isn't Working For Me [Last one closed , idk how to fix]

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I am fairly new to blender, I have been trying to use the compositing in blender to create a mist pass to make my underwater scene look more underwater like if you know what I mean
(a water fade, cant see objects further away, they fade out) and I have watched multiple tutorials but the mist pass never shows in the final render or moving around the scene
in the compositing tab the background only ever shows as black and don't know what to do

Reply 1 - I have got an image for you of my compositing tab, the background also disappeares when I add and connect different nodes[image]

Reply 2 - During this time I figured out that I wasn't receiving answers because I didn't have enough detail in my question, I stumbled across another stack exchange post that was made 4 years ago
that showed an image of how to make a mist pass and it actually worked, I'll insert it above

But now I am Having The issue of It not rendering in the final render, does anyone have any ideas

Answer (score 1):

The final render depends on the background you make here,click it and set the Environment Texture.

[image]

Comment: Thank you I fixed it